# Usage of JAXB @XMLIDREF and @XMLID

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I want to save Data in XML with Java.

The XML should look like the following:

```
<person>
    <id>101</id>
    <name>test name</name>
</person>
<person>
    <id>202</id>
    <name>another name</name>
</person>

<company>
    <bureau1>
        <id>101</id>
        <id>202</id>
    </bureau1>
    <bureau2>
        <id>202</id>
    </bureau2>
<company>
```

How do I do that, with using of JAXB. If I tried it, I will get the company part, but
I can not export the Person-Data. I'm searching for days to get a solution.

---

Yes, here is an example of classes and XML. But where are the Information to the Persons?

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Company {

    private String companyNo;
    private String name;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="employee")
    @XmlElement(name="person")
    @XmlIDREF
    private List<Person> employee;
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Person {

    @XmlID
    private String pId;
    private String name;
}

public class CompanyExport {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        List<Person> employee = new ArrayList<Person>();

        Person p1 = new Person();
        p1.setName("Name1");
        p1.setPId("p101");
        employee.add(p1);

        Person p2 = new Person();
        p2.setName("Name2");
        p2.setPId("p202");
        employee.add(p2);

        Person p3 = new Person();
        p3.setName("Name3");
        p3.setPId("p303");
        employee.add(p3);

        Company c = new Company();
        c.setEmployee(employee);
        c.setCompanyNo("c101");
        c.setName("JAXB Company1");

        try (FileOutputStream ausgabe = new FileOutputStream(new File("CompanyExport.xml"))){
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Company.class);

            Marshaller jMarshall = context.createMarshaller();
            jMarshall.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            jMarshall.marshal(c, ausgabe);

            System.out.println("DONE!");
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        //} catch (SAXException e) {
        //  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        //  e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<company>
    <companyNo>c101</companyNo>
    <name>JAXB Company1</name>
    <employee>
        <person>p101</person>
        <person>p202</person>
        <person>p303</person>
    </employee>
</company>
```

Comment: Do you have any code that you have tried to show us?

Comment: See the example here: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/beans/bean-xml-serialization/

Comment: Here is an example that should help:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/jaxb-and-shared-references-xmlid-and.html

Comment: Please provide a full sample of what you want the xml to be like (root element included)

Comment: I added an class, which contains all data, and now it works, thank you for your help